# Hotlink prevention without relying on referer?

Tags: hotlinking

Is there a way to stop the hotlinking of images without relying on referers?
I searched for hours and all seem to do the same, problem is i must allow empty referers and when i access the site hotlinking (incognito) i still see the images most likely because there's no referer since i'm accessing directly.

So question is, is there another method? Can't i grab the domain name where the image was placed and compare it to mine? I guess not? No good solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by `hotlinking (incognito)`?

Comment: I means that i'm sure the image is not cached by the browser because i access the hotlinker site using incognito mode that bypasses cache.